# how to play on browser a mp4 received by a Jquery post method?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, mp4

I'm using moodle webservice with jquery requests and everything works fine, but when I got a video file from webservice something different happens: I receive a string stream that is the source of MP4 file.

The code looks like:

```
 $.post(
     'webservice.com/pluginfile.php/butterfly.mp4', 
     {'token':'XYZ123'}, 
     function(data) {
         console.log(data)// return a string as follow
         // how to use data as a resource to <video> tag?
     }, '')
```

The return of this request is:

```
>ftypmp42isommp42¨²moovlmvhdÒ#Ò#_hÑ@!iodsOÿÿÿÿÿ"Ùtrak\tkhdÒ#Ò#d¸@´"umdia mdhdÒ#Ò#'|øÇDhdlrvideMainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler"  minfvmhd$dinfdrefurl !Éstblstsdavc1´HH
AVC Codingÿÿ3avcCMÿágM@R ?>Ñ¡bähëÍHsttsKè(stsc
»@stszK"æ¿L¸ÏXáí1¡¤1)»/E
þ
´
Æ
y
>
é
```

The question is: how to convert this return in a resource to a  tag? 
This is a blob resource?

I try put the webservice link in src attribute of source tag, but the webservice don't accepts GET request:

```
<video>
    <source src="webservice.com/pluginfile.php/butterfly.mp4&token=XYZ123" type="video/mp4">
</video>
// URL above don't work.
```

Please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full $.ajax method to be able to get the video as a blob.
Then you can convert it to a url and set it to the src of the video tag

jQuery 3 example

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'webservice.com/pluginfile.php/butterfly.mp4&token=XYZ123',
        xhrFields:{
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        data: {'token':'XYZ123'},
        success: function(data){
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            $('video').prop('src', url.createObjectURL(data));
        },
        error:function(){

        }
});
```